# extract values from json format list

Tags: python, json, dataframe, geojson

I have a list with json data as below:

```
txt
```

["{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [35.51635659, 139.5662442]}",
 "{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [51.50178423, -0.05362636]}"]

I'm trying to extract the long and lat from coordinates but i'm really struggling with this.

When I try:

```
for each in txt:
    print(each)
```

it returns:

{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [35.51635659, 139.5662442]}
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [51.50178423, -0.05362636]}

when i try:

```
json_normalize(json.loads(txt))
```

I get the following error:

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 json_normalize(json.loads(txt))
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json__init__.py in loads(s, encoding,
>   cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
>   object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       339     else:
>       340         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
>   --> 341             raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
>       342                             f'not {s.**class**.**name**}')
>       343         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
>
> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: 1 for each in txt:
----> 2     print(each['coordinates'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Ah, the dict seems to be in string for some reason :). Why are they strings ?

Comment: the data was originally in a dataframe, I looped through it: for each in cords['geo']:
    txt.append(each)

Comment: `import ast; for each in txt:..x = ast.literal_eval(each);..print(x['coordinates'])`

Comment: Why is `cords['geo']` in strings ? :)

Comment: beautiful thank you :-)  ; you saved my day. FYI you meant : print(x['coordinates'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is a string, so you'd need to either use `ast.literal_eval()`, or replace with double quotes then use `json.loads()`. either way can get the coordianates:

Given:

```
txt = ["{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [35.51635659, 139.5662442]}", "{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [51.50178423, -0.05362636]}"]
```

Option 1:

```
import json

for each in txt:
    each = each.replace("'", '"')
    jsonObj = json.loads(each) 
    print (jsonObj['coordinates'])
```

Option 2:

```
import ast

for each in txt:
    each = ast.literal_eval(each)
    print(each['coordinates'])
```

**Output:**

```
[35.51635659, 139.5662442]
[51.50178423, -0.05362636]
```